# sending colored output using linux mail/mailx

Tags: linux, mailx

I'm using mailx to send colored output via email:

```
git diff | mailx -s "code diff output" usrname@srv.com
```

Output of git diff is colored but the received mail is plain.

Comment: Did my command work? If yes, then accept the answer.

Comment: the command worked. how do you read ascii encoding in windows?

Comment: You need to use different editor. http://web.archive.org/web/20110807120105/http://www.defacto2.net/nfo-files.cfm Or if you are viewing it on terminal, then https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases)

Comment: If you found answer useful, please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
git diff --color=always | mailx -s "code diff output" usrname@srv.com
```

But when you read it will show asci character for color. So pipe to cat for reading:

```
mailx | cat
```